# Drive-by downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Three hours ago someone downvoted without comment five of my recent contributions that have nothing in common but being five of my recent contributions.  Should I be suspicious, and if so, is there something one should do?

Comment: If you want to know more about serial voting, you might have a look at this meta.SO post: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)
Perhaps also the questions tagged ([meta-tag:serial-voting]) at this meta might be of interest.

Answer (score 18):

There is nothing you should do, just wait for the serial voting reversal script to run. It runs once every 24 hours and reverses such abnormal voting patterns.

Comment: Never heard of it before.  Thanks.

Comment: I haevn't seen this happen on stackexchange before.  I've seen malicious down-voting, but not "serial" down-voting.

Comment: @Michael: Tragically, it happens more often than you'd hope.

Comment: What exactly defines "abnormal voting patterns?"

Comment: @anorton mostly it is voting based on the user, and not on the actual posts. The exact algorithm is not public, though.

Comment: If you look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1120/jonas-teuwen?tab=reputation) at May 18 you will see what appears to be an instance of serial down voting that did not get detected by the script. The algorithm is not flawless. I bet if you down vote one post a day you can also remain undetected.

Comment: @MattN. If I downvote 3 posts in the same day this means that I'm a serial downvoter??? (Even they apply to the same user I don't think I should be labeled as such, cause I can follow a user questions/answers someday just for mathematical reasons.) Btw, I consider the downvoting a kind of measure of the relevance of some question/answer, and I'd like to see the good answers having many upvotes and the useless answers having much less in order to know instantly that there is no reason to waste my time with them. But all these discussions I think made many users to be afraid of downvoting.

Comment: @MattN. The algorithm can't catch everything, and in your example with only three votes even a human will have a hard time finding out the intent behind the votes. But you still won't get away with large-scale vote abuse like your one vote a day example, even if the script doesn't trigger, there are tools available to moderators that would show such a pattern and they then can ask SE to remove those votes.

Comment: @MadScientist Ah, good, thanks. Then all one has to do is to wait for a suspicious number of down votes on posts that seem valid.